# Asp.net MVC 3 Dropdown List Database Population remove item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have a dropdown list where it is populated from the database I want to remove an a number from the options list. This is the code

```
var id= ctx.tableMaster.Select(x => x.id).Where(x != "0").Distinct();
```

What would I put in the were statement to check if the idis not equal to 0

Thanks

Comment: for starters you should rewrite your LINQ to this `ctx.tableMaster.FirstOrDefault(x => !x.id.Equals(0));`

Comment: @No1_Melman, this won't work as the OP want's a distinct list

Comment: I can ignore the `Distinct()` function, noting that `Id` fields should be unique, My technique is far more efficient I would say, and will produce a distinct object. So that is why mine should be used! Using his is confusing as it is a contradictory of database rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `id` an integer? If so, you don't need quotes:

```
var idList = ctx.tableMaster.Where(x => x.id != 0).Select(x => x.id).Distinct();
```

Comment: it worked, but says I have to wait 8 minutes to accept your anwser!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this too

```
var results = ctx.tableMaster.FindAll(x => !x.id.Equals(0));
```

If you have to ignore multiple ids

```
List<int> ignoreIds = new List<int>() { 0, 1, 5, 9};
var results = ctx.tableMaster.FindAll(x => !ignoreIds.Contains(x.id));
```